# jQuery document ready conflicting with window onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hack together a video gallery. I am using jQuery to make a slide out panel 
which is simple. I am also using jQuery for scrolling thumbnails. They both work beautifully. The problem is that I need the scrolling thubmnails to work inside the slide out panel but it won't. I think it has to do with the two functions on being document ready and the other being  window onload. I'm not sure cause I am new to jQuery. Can any one help with this.

Here is the slide out panel function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
});
});
```

And her is the scrolling function.

```
 <script>
 jQuery.noConflict() 
(function($){
window.onload=function(){ 
$("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({ 
    scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
    scrollerOrientation:"horizontal", 
    scrollSpeed:2, 
    scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
    scrollEasingAmount:600, 
    acceleration:4, 
    scrollSpeed:800, 
    noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
    autoScrolling:0, 
    autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
    autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
    autoScrollingDelay:500 
});
}
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Can anyone see anything here that would conflict with each other?

Here is the whole html.

```
 <html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Vertical Sliding Info Panel With jQuery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="jquery.thumbnailScroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="panel">
<div>
<div id="tS2" class="jThumbnailScroller">
<div class="jTscrollerContainer">
    <div class="jTscroller">
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img1.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img2.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img3.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img4.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img5.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img6.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img7.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img8.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img9.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img10.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img11.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img12.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img13.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img14.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img15.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img16.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img17.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img18.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img19.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="thumbs/img20.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="jTscrollerPrevButton"></a>
<a href="#" class="jTscrollerNextButton"></a>
</div>
<!-- thumbnail scroller markup end -->

<script>
/* jQuery.noConflict() for using the plugin along with other libraries. 
 You can remove it if you won't use other libraries (e.g. prototype, scriptaculous etc.) or 
 if you include jQuery before other libraries in yourdocument's head tag. 
 [more info: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries] */
jQuery.noConflict(); 
/* calling thumbnailScroller function with options as parameters */
(function($){
window.onload=function(){ 
$("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({ 
    scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
    scrollerOrientation:"horizontal", 
    scrollSpeed:2, 
    scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
    scrollEasingAmount:600, 
    acceleration:4, 
    scrollSpeed:800, 
    noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
    autoScrolling:0, 
    autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
    autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
    autoScrollingDelay:500 
});
}
})(jQuery);
 </script>
<!-- thumbnailScroller script -->
<script src="jquery.thumbnailScroller.js"></script>
</div>
</div>
<a class="trigger" href="#">infos</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is going on with your jquery includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thumbnailScroller plugin seems to need to calculate the dimensions of the wrapper of the thumbs. In your case, the wrapper is initially not displayed and it may get the plugin confused.

You could try to hide the .panel element only after having executed the plugin.

```
jQuery.noConflict(); 
/* calling thumbnailScroller function with options as parameters */
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".trigger").click(function(){
            $(".panel").toggle("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            return false;
        });
    });
    window.onload=function(){ 
        $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({ 
            scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
            scrollerOrientation:"horizontal", 
            scrollSpeed:2, 
            scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
            scrollEasingAmount:600, 
            acceleration:4, 
            scrollSpeed:800, 
            noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
            autoScrolling:0, 
            autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
            autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
            autoScrollingDelay:500 
        });

        // Hide the .panel only now :
        $(".panel").hide();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

(You'll need to modify you CSS so that the .panel is initially displayed)

Comment: Perfect Thank you. It flashes some little dots for a split second when the page loads but I can live with that. As soon as I have enough rep I will one up this.

Comment: To prevent flashing, you may initialize .panel to visibility:hidden so that its dimensions are ok. And instead of using `hide()` then, you would use `css({visibility:'visible',display:'none'})` ?

Answer (score 1):

The document.ready will get executed as soon as your dom/document is ready but window.load will be executed only after all objects(images/text) are loaded in momery.

i have faced the similer kind of problem where i was using document.ready for making scroller for my list of multiple images but as some of images were large in size so before loading those images the document.ready get fired and faced the issue..

so later on i changed it with window.load so now with window.load my scroller creation process will only get fired after when all images loads in memory properly..

hope this will help you to get solution..

Comment: My image scroller works great outside of the slide out panel. But if I put it inside the div that the slide out panel calls to it only shows one image and no scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using 2 document.ready function in the same page . It will definitely make a conflict. Just avoid the script declaration at the begining and try.

You need only this much js code inside script tag. This will work for you.

```
jQuery.noConflict(); /* calling thumbnailScroller function with options as parameters*/
(function($){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
       $(".panel").toggle("fast");
       $(this).toggleClass("active");
      return false;
    });


window.onload=function(){ 
    $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({ 
    scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
    scrollerOrientation:"horizontal", 
    scrollSpeed:2, 
    scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
    scrollEasingAmount:600, 
    acceleration:4, 
    scrollSpeed:800, 
    noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
    autoScrolling:0, 
    autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
    autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
    autoScrollingDelay:500 
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This stops my panel from sliding out at all.

Comment: Using 2 document.ready functions will definitely NOT make a conflict. The functions are registered in order to the event listener and will be executed in that order when document's ready.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove double click event binding for `$(".trigger").click(...)`, only the second one is needed. Then try to move this binding after `thumbnailScroller` initialization inside window.onload, bacause window.onload fires much after DOM ready event. And remove `(function($){` wrapping around window.onload as unnecessary. Try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // Initialize scroller
    $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({ ... });

    // Initialize panel
    $(".trigger").click(function() {
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This is definitely much cleaner code but it has the same result.

Comment: My panel pops out like it should but the scroller inside it wont scroll and only shows one image.

Comment: Probably this is because your scroller is hidden by the moment of initialization and jQuery width() function returns 0 width for hidden images. `.css('width')` should work but in this case you have to tweak plugin code - not good. Not sure but maybe setting `width` and `height` attributes for the images can do the job.