# (window).load and (document).ready functions are conflicting

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the 2 jquerys to work without conflicting!

Here is my code:

```
(function($){ //This functions first parameter is named $
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // tabbed boxes
        $('#tabs div').hide();
        $('#tabs div:first').show();
        $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
        $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){ 
            $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
            var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
            $('#tabs div').hide();
            $(currentTab).show();
            return false;
        });
    });

    $(window).load(function(){
        // jQuery Lightbox
        var lightboxPath = "/js/jquery-lightbox/";
        $("a[rel='group1']").lightBox({
            imageLoading:lightboxPath+"img/lightbox-ico-loading.gif",
            imageBtnPrev:lightboxPath+"img/lightbox-btn-prev.gif",
            imageBtnNext:lightboxPath+"img/lightbox-btn-next.gif",
            imageBtnClose:lightboxPath+"img/lightbox-btn-close.gif",
            imageBlank:lightboxPath+"img/lightbox-blank.gif"
        });

        // Photo gallery > Standard
        $(".photosgallery-std").sliderkit({
            mousewheel:true,
            shownavitems:7,
            //navfx:"none",
            panelbtnshover:true,
            auto:true,
            circular:true,
            navscrollatend:true,
            counter:true
        });
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Please can anyone help :)

Comment: You need to explain what is going wrong - don't just say they're conflicting.

Comment: See [jQuery document ready conflicting with window onload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676907/jquery-document-ready-conflicting-with-window-onload)

Comment: Have you tested it by putting `$(window).load` in `doc ready` handler?

Comment: Sorry, my question is how can i get the 2 to work together?  I can get them to work seperately but then when i have them both on the same page the tabs jquery works but the lightbox and photogallery don´t work.

Comment: I have tried "jQuery document ready conflicting with window onload" but had no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to put this outside of `()(jQuery);`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // tabbed boxes
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){ 
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
        $('#tabs div').hide();
        $(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
});

(function($){ //This functions first parameter is named $
$(window).load(function(){
    // jQuery Lightbox
    var lightboxPath = "/js/jquery-lightbox/";
    $("a[rel='group1']").lightBox({
        imageLoading:lightboxPath+"img/lightbox-ico-loading.gif",
        imageBtnPrev:lightboxPath+"img/lightbox-btn-prev.gif",
        imageBtnNext:lightboxPath+"img/lightbox-btn-next.gif",
        imageBtnClose:lightboxPath+"img/lightbox-btn-close.gif",
        imageBlank:lightboxPath+"img/lightbox-blank.gif"
    });

    // Photo gallery > Standard
    $(".photosgallery-std").sliderkit({
        mousewheel:true,
        shownavitems:7,
        //navfx:"none",
        panelbtnshover:true,
        auto:true,
        circular:true,
        navscrollatend:true,
        counter:true
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but still have the same problem, the tabs jquery works but the lightbox and photo gallery do not.

Comment: try replacing with this `jQuery(function($))`

Comment: Do you mean replace the (jQuery) with jQuery(function($)) ?

Comment: ah, ok.  I have just tried that and it was the same except the tabs also doesn't work

Comment: Right, i have managed to fix the problem i was having but it wasn't the problem that i thought it was originally.  Thank you Jai, your answer helped, i just couldn´t see the content iof the gallery in the tab as it was in a div and the jquery $('#tabs div').hide(); was hiding it.  I have changed the divs inside the tabs to span and it is now workinging tickitty-boo!  Thanks for your help!